# Truncation of the product of operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wick-theorem

Given that the operators $A,B $ and $C$ commute with each other, how can we justify the following approximations:
  $<ABC> ≈ <A><BC> + <AB><C> + <AC><B>$ - 2$<A><B><C>$
Where <> is the usual notation for expectation value.

Comment: That's false in general, I should think - though possibly justified in specific circumstances. Where did you see these?

Comment: These appear in the study of quantum correlations between different modes inside a cavity.

Comment: That level of detail will make it very hard to answer unless you stumble on an expert in that specific subfield. At the very least you should provide a reference.

Comment: These approximations are usually completely false, and there is no general way to justify them unless you are in a very specific situation. For instance, if two operators approximately commute, you can sometimes justify these approximations. So *if* you make them, they must be accompanied by arguments as to *why* you can make them.